# Hiding WordPress behind IIS redirects

Tags: redirect, iis

We have a main .NET application that I do not have much ability to change, but we would like to move some of the links that are on it to WordPress so that marketing can update them on a regular basis without involving a developer. For security reasons, I can't install WordPress on the servers with the main application.

Has anyone ever used URL rewriting rules in IIS to mask a WordPress site on a different server?

```
example: http://www.dominan.com/Info -> http://www2.domain.com:8080/About-Company
```

or

```
example 2: http://www.dominan.com/Info -> http://192.168.x.x:8080/About-Company
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make url rewrites on iis, just like you would on apache. Like making a .htaccess file.

check out: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/ for more information how to do this on iis.